# css Hyphens not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In my project paragraph (in p tag) i have give text-align:justify; but in some words there more space comes so for this solution i try:
HTML code:

```
<p>What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
```

CSS code:

```
p{
    text-align:justify;
    word-break: break-all;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

but in this code mozilla works but not work in chrome,for this i try

```
p{
    text-align:justify;
    -ms-word-break: break-all; 
    word-break: break-all; 
    word-break: break-word; 
   -webkit-hyphens: auto; 
   -moz-hyphens: auto; 
   hyphens: auto;
}
```

below css there -webkit- is used for chrome right but still not working please help, please give the solutions......

Comment: In case anyone else made the mistake I did, hyphens only work if you declare the language in the HTML tag. for example:
`<html lang="en-GB">`

Answer (score 7):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=652964) in Chrome for Windows, Linux, and ChromeOS.

Comment: im using google chrome latest version (62.0.3202.94).

Comment: @designmetR — So? That bug isn't marked as "fixed" in any version.

Comment: Is there any other solution because its working fine in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: this bug bit me tooo !